# UI not Updating as per orientation in ios8 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, screen-orientation

I am using Swift langue for my current project. I m trying to add landscape support for my project. for this i used the following steps
in ViewDidLoad

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "DeviceRotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

in DeviceRotated(), changed all controls positions as per orientation.

Included

```
  override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool{

    return true
}
```

Deployment Info as

[image: Deployment info]

Now the app UI as follows
[image: Potrait]
[image: LandScape Right]
[image: LandScape Left]

In AppDelegate file i have this code

```
 window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

if (some Bool condition)  {
        let rootViewController = PlayersViewController()
        let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true
        window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }else{

        let rootViewController: ViewController = ViewController()
        let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Will this effect on orientation?

Please share your ideas. 
Thanks

Comment: check your ipad...is other app is also doing same things....

Comment: Checked it working fine for other apps. In current app only have this problem

Comment: Is `DeviceRotated` being called? Is `DeviceRotated` setting the layout to the correct version?

Comment: emrys57 , i updated my question .Please take a look once and suggest me for solution

Comment: It would help if you could find out if `DeviceRotated` was being called and made the right decision. Plus, do any of your VCs implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations`? Put a print in any that do.

Comment: I found the problem. Because of code used in AppDelegate(updated in question). With out that code for navigation controller , app UI changing correctly . Do you have any idea how to change initial VC from Appdelegate

Comment: I suggest you ask a new, more specific, question.